# Running the setup.exe silently with MST transform from powershell

Tags: powershell, wix, installshield

I was able to run the silent installation for the `setup.exe` by running the below command from the command prompt

```
setup.exe -s -v"/l*v \"c:\testmstedited1.log\" -qn TRANSFORMS=\"C:\p\n\d\phx\a\m\ResponseTransform.Mst\"""
```

But when I am running the same command from powershell i am gettnig `msiexec.exe` popup error. Below is the command i tried in powershell for this.

```
& $SetupFilePath\setup.exe -s -v"/l*v \"c:\testmstedited1.log\" /qn TRANSFORMS=\"$SetupFilePath\ResponseTransform.Mst\""
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: `& $SetupFilePath\setup.exe -s -v"/l*v ""c:\testmstedited1.log"" /qn TRANSFORMS=""$SetupFilePath\ResponseTransform.Mst"""` to escape a quote you have to use double-double-quotes `""`